# Movie about a girl who meets a dead boy in her dreams

Tags: story-identification, movie

I’m looking for a movie.

1. A girl (I’m not sure it could be a boy) has dreams with a guy who’s dying. They meet in dreams and fall in love.
2. And she’s looking for that guy but he’s already dead. And his family recognize her name. Because he had the same dreams with her and wrote everything about it on diary.

I think this movie was from like 2008~2013?

Comment: Similar, if sex-swapped, "A Message from Charity", which aired on The Twilight Zone.

Comment: It's kinda like "Paperhouse" except I feel different things about it would be remembered more, and it was from the 80s.

Comment: What language/country did you watch it in? Live action or animated? Are you sure it was a movie, or could it have been an episode of a tv show?

Comment: Oh! It was a movie and it’s in English. US english